# MongoDB: How to find distinct array pairs in mongo collection?

Tags: mongodb

I have a mongo collection which looks like this:

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("59ca2d8f17b56667cd0cd50a"), "gps" : [ 2, 1 ] }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("59ca2da317b56667cd0cd50b"), "gps" : [ 2, 1 ] }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("59ca2db817b56667cd0cd50c"), "gps" : [ 3, 2 ] }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("59ca2dc717b56667cd0cd50d"), "gps" : [ 3, 2 ] }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("59ca2dcf17b56667cd0cd50e"), "gps" : [ 4, 5 ] }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("59ca2dda17b56667cd0cd50f"), "gps" : [ 5, 7 ] }
```

I want to filter out all the duplicate gps pairs. So my desired output is:

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("59ca2d8f17b56667cd0cd50a"), "gps" : [ 2, 1 ] }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("59ca2db817b56667cd0cd50c"), "gps" : [ 3, 2 ] }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("59ca2dcf17b56667cd0cd50e"), "gps" : [ 4, 5 ] }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("59ca2dda17b56667cd0cd50f"), "gps" : [ 5, 7 ] }
```

How to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if as robjwilkins mentioned, you want to keep the original id, you can do so with a $first function as below:

```
db.collection.aggregate([{$group:{_id:"$gps" ,firstid: { $first: "$_id" }}}])
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with an aggregate query:

```
db.collection.aggregate([{$group:{_id:"$gps"}}])
```

This will give output like:

```
{ "_id" : [ 5, 7 ] }
{ "_id" : [ 4, 5 ] }
{ "_id" : [ 3, 2 ] }
{ "_id" : [ 2, 1 ] }
```

but you will be missing the `_id` from the original documents (not sure if this matters to you?)

Answer (score 1):

And if you would like to **delete them permanently**:

```
db.yourCollection.find({},{gps:1})
    .sort({_id:1})
    .forEach(function(doc){
        db.yourCollection.remove({_id:{$gt:doc._id}, gps:doc.gps
        });
     }
)
```